Cannot connect AirPods Pro with Ubuntu 22.04 as headset
Does anybody know how I can connect my AirPods Pro with my Ubuntu 22.04 system?
I've seen posts like this or this but the former doesn't connect the AirPods Pro as a headset but rather as simply headphones while the latter seems to only work for 18.04 and 20.04 since the ofono-phonesim package cannot be installed on 22.04.
